# API works in postman but not with axios in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Here is my API calls:
[using postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y01Ka.png)
It works fine in postman but when I try
[using axios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn9ZC.png)

```
export const getAccountBalance = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
        dispatch({
        type: BALANCE_FETCH_REQUEST,
        });
    
        const {
        userLogin: { userInfo },
        } = getState();
    
        const config = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
        },
        };
        const { data } = await axios.get(`getAccountByAccountNo?accountNo=${id}`,config);
        console.log(data);
        dispatch({
            type: BALANCE_FETCH_SUCCESS,
            payload: data,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: BALANCE_FETCH_FAIL,
            payload:
            error.response && error.response.data.message
                ? error.response.data.message
                : error.message,
        });
    }
};
```

Its exactly the same URL but its giving 404 not found
[404 not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M01TV.png) response

Please help me, I have to submit this college project!!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to access absolute url path

```
const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:6969/v1/api/getAccountByAccountNo?accountNo
```

Comment: i have added the base url as proxy

Comment: show the proxy ?

Comment: "name": "banking-react-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:6969/v1/api/",
  "private": true,

Comment: well i tried without the proxy and now its wrking thanks

Comment: yeah seems like proxy is not connected properly

Comment: can you compare the url,  headers  from  postman and axios (using browser dev tools), it will give you a good idea of what could be wrong, you can post the pictures in the question